# Why hasn't Linux version number moved beyond 2.6?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, version-numbering

Before 2.6 Linux moved up from 2.0 to 2.2 to 2.4 every few years. Why did it stop at 2.6?

Is the version number ever going to go beyond 2.6?

Comment: Who says it *has* to keep moving? Version number != product quality.

Comment: It is the nature of things to develop rapidly at first, then change more slowly as it matures. Is there something else you need it to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is moving. It is just first two digits became irrelevant. From the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel):

> Since 2004, after version 2.6.0 was
>   released, the kernel developers held
>   several discussions regarding the
>   release and version scheme and
>   ultimately Linus Torvalds and others
>   decided that a much shorter release
>   cycle would be beneficial. Since then,
>   the version has been composed of three
>   or four numbers. The first two numbers
>   became largely irrelevant, and the
>   third number is the actual version of
>   the kernel. The fourth number accounts
>   for bug and security fixes (only) to
>   the kernel version.